# How to get values from dynamic CheckBoxes and RadioButtons in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-radiobutton

I'm getting bellow Json response according to with I'm creating dynamic layout. I can create dynamic checkboxes and Radio Buttons but, I'm unable to fetch the values from those dynamic checkboxes and Radio Buttons. I tried to get the instance of CheckBox on Button click but can not get the values. The only time I'm getting the values is on setting checkedchangelistener on CheckBoxes. How to get values from both CheckBoxes and RadioButtons?

```css
[
  {
    "QId": 15,
    "Questions": "Have you taken any medication?",
    "InputType": "cb",
    "NoOfInputs": "2",    
    "QuestionOptions": [
      "Yes",
      "No"
    ]
  },
  {
    "QId": 16,
    "Questions": "Test Question for a radio button",
    "InputType": "rb",
    "NoOfInputs": "4",
    "QuestionOptions": [
      "Yes",
      "No",
      "May be",
      "May not be"
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Button button;
    private LinearLayout linear, newcbll;
    private Model model;
    private LinkedHashMap<String,String> mappy = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private ArrayList<Model> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<DynamicModel> dynamolist = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> optionlist = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int arraycout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainact);

        arraycout = 0;

        linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        GetAllQuestion();

        model = new Model();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("sammy_total_count: "+arraycout);
                for(int i=0; i<arraycout; i++) {
                    //Model model = arraylist.get(i);
                    //DynamicModel dynamo = new DynamicModel();
                    View nextChild = newcbll.getChildAt(i);

                   if(nextChild instanceof CheckBox){
                       CheckBox check = (CheckBox)nextChild;
                       if(check.isChecked()){
                           /*optionlist.add(check.getText().toString());
                           dynamo.setQoptions(optionlist);*/

                           System.out.println("sammy_Checkbox_values: "+check.getText().toString());
                       }
                   }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void GetAllQuestion(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "My_Url", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ja = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String QId = ja.getString("QId");
                        String Questions = ja.getString("Questions");
                        String InputType = ja.getString("InputType");
                        String NoOfInputs = ja.getString("NoOfInputs");
                        JSONArray Qoption = ja.getJSONArray("QuestionOptions");
                        if(Qoption != null && Qoption.length() > 0 ){
                            for(int j=0; j<Qoption.length(); j++){
                                mappy.put(String.valueOf(j), Qoption.getString(j));
                            }

                        }
                        model = new Model();
                        model.setQId(QId);
                        model.setQuestions(Questions);
                        model.setInputType(InputType);
                        model.setNoOfInputs(NoOfInputs);
                        model.setMamppy(mappy);
                        arraycout=jarr.length();
                        arraylist.add(model);

                        if(InputType.equals("cb")){
                            Set<?> set = mappy.entrySet();
                            Iterator<?> iterator = set.iterator();
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                                /*System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
                                System.out.println(me.getValue());*/
                                newcbll = new LinearLayout(NextActivity.this);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                newcbll.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(NextActivity.this);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams checkparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                checkBox.setLayoutParams(checkparams);
                                checkBox.setId(Integer.parseInt(me.getKey().toString()));
                                checkBox.setText(me.getValue().toString());
                                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(handleCheck(checkBox));
                                newcbll.addView(checkBox);
                                linear.addView(newcbll);

                            }


                        }

                    }




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }


        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NextActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener handleCheck (final CheckBox chk){
        return new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    System.out.println("sammy_cblistener "+buttonView.getText());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the checkbox instances on button click? You only need to know the answers chosen by the user, right? Update your datastructure(Arraylist) on every checked change event and manipulate it.

Comment: As in the case of listview we can get other details from the model class if we know the position. I would like to know the other details here that I entered in the `Model` class.  Such that if user selects "Yes" from the first array how to get the `Qid` as 15?

Comment: Instead of setting the value if j inside the for loop as key in your mappy hashmap, use your Qid as the key. Then from checkedchangelistener, you can retrieve the qid as the compundbutton's tag.

Comment: Can you me show me how to do it?